# Best approach to find missing logins and missing jobs between principal and mirror server

Tags: sql-server-2012, mirroring

I am doing a manual comparison of the logins and jobs between Principal and Secondary server, when doing database failover from P to S. I copy both the logins and jobs from one server to excel and compare them to those on the other.

Could someone please suggest a way to automate at least part of this check?

Note - I am doing this before doing a database failover as a **pre**-check, just to ensure that the secondary isn't missing anything as compared to the principal, so as to avoid a break after mirroring database failover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Power Shell worked for me. I have this as part of bigger script, I am only providing sections of it. Hopefully you can put it together.

```
FUNCTION report-status-primary 
    {
        PARAM (
                $Check,
                $Variable,
                $Primary,
                $Secondary
              )

        WRITE-HOST "Checking $Check on $Primary..." -ForegroundColor Yellow
        IF ($Variable)

            {

                WRITE-HOST "$Check on $primary not on $secondary" -ForegroundColor Red
                $Variable
            }
        ELSE
            {
                WRITE-HOST "Match" -ForegroundColor Green
            }     
        WRITE-HOST "------------------------------------------------------------" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }

  FUNCTION report-status-secondary 
    {
        PARAM (
                $Check,
                $Variable,
                $Primary,
                $Secondary
              )

        WRITE-HOST "Checking $Check on $Secondary..." -ForegroundColor Yellow
        IF ($Variable)

            {

                WRITE-HOST "$Check on $Secondary not on $primary" -ForegroundColor Red
                $Variable
            }
        ELSE
            {
                WRITE-HOST "Match" -ForegroundColor Green
            }     
        WRITE-HOST "------------------------------------------------------------" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }
```

Variable:

```
$SourceSQLServer = 'Primary Server'
$TargetSQLServer = 'Secondary Server'

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | Out-Null
$SourceServer = New-Object 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Server' ($SourceSQLServer)
$TargetServer  = New-Object 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Server' ($TargetSQLServer)

# -- Jobs
$JobsSNT = $SourceServer.JobServer.Jobs.name | where {($TargetServer.JobServer.Jobs.name -notcontains $_) -and $_ -notlike "*]__*" }
$JobsTNS = $TargetServer.JobServer.Jobs.name | where {($SourceServer.JobServer.Jobs.name -notcontains $_) -and $_ -notlike "*]__*" }

# -- Logins
$LoginsSNT = $SourceServer.Logins.name | where {$TargetServer.Logins.name -notcontains $_}
$LoginsTNS = $TargetServer.Logins.name | where {$SourceServer.Logins.name -notcontains $_}
```

Reporting:

```
report-status-primary -check 'Jobs' -variable $JobsSNT -primary $SourceServer -secondary $TargetServer 
report-status-secondary -check 'Jobs' -variable $JobsTNS -primary $SourceServer -secondary $TargetServer 

report-status-primary -check 'Logins' -variable $LoginsSNT -primary $SourceServer -secondary $TargetServer 
report-status-secondary -check 'Logins' -variable $LoginsTNS -primary $SourceServer -secondary $TargetServer
```

Here is a sample output I get running this script.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the script. Since i am not that good in Powershell, getting hard time in putting this together. I tried using this but keep getting errors here there. Not sure if there is SQL query to do this without using linked server. Appreciate you taking time and answering,

Comment: I literally ran the code that I posted by replacing server name and I get an output as expected.  Edited answer with a sample output.

Comment: Perfect, i got that working. But is there a way to send this as results. Like what i f i want to automate this?

Comment: You can run this as a SQL Agent scheduled job and email the report.  There are many examples, search in google. If this answers your original question please accept the answer by so other users do not think that you are still looking for an answer plus others can also benefit from this answer.